# How to appoint Putrika? What is the process of appointing Putrika?

Tags: marriage, children, heaven

1. It is being said that if someone doesn't have a son , he can appoint one of his daughter as Putrika and find a man who is willing to marry his daughter and put condition on him that son born from this daughter will be considered as heir of his maternal grandfather (Nana)

   This way one can continue his lineage without having a son.

   **What is the process of appointing daughter as Putrika ?**
2. My second question is connected to this question. **Can son born from such a marriage (i.e. in which the bride is Putrika) can also become heir of the husband ?**
   If No , then the man can take this woman only as his second or third or subsequent wife only. ( Arjun married Chitrangda ,Ulupi this way as took them as his third and fourth wives)